# Bootstrap Carousel - View Slides by Category

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstraps Carousel, I have a list of items.  Each item has a "category" assigned to them of my choosing.  The logic I am trying to use is:

1. Load the carousel
2. Click on the next arrow
3. Find the "next item" in the list which has category = landscape
4. Set as "Active" and jump/skip to that slide
5. Repeat steps 2 through 4

Here is the code I'm using but not currently working..

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <div class="item landscape active">...image</div>
   <div class="item">...image</div>
   <div class="item">...image</div>
   <div class="item">...image</div>
   <div class="item landscape">...image</div>
   <div class="item">...image</div>
   <div class="item landscape">...image</div>
```

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
 var active = $(e.target).find('.carousel-inner > .item.active');
 var from = active.index();
 var next = $(e.target).find('.carousel-inner > .item.landscape');
 var to = next.index();
});
```

Comment: Can't reorder them by category? I mean, show first the *landscape* ones

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  I found a clue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468089/how-to-tell-bootstrap-carousel-to-skip-an-element-or-class).  Basically, the answer is to remove the "item" class from the slides which you don't want to show.